# Обособление обстоятельства, выраженного одиночным деепричастием

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастия

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему в этом предложении обособляется деепричастие, если оно одиночное, связано со сказуемым и приближается к наречию в данном контексте?

> После обеда я, в самом веселом расположении духа, припрыгивая,
> отправился в залу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

П р а в и л ь н о е предложение Л. Толстого (["Детство"](https://ruslit.traumlibrary.net/book/tolstoy-ln-ss22-01/tolstoy-ln-ss22-01.html), гл. XIII) выглядит так.

> После обеда я в самом веселом расположении духа, припрыгивая, отправился в залу, как вдруг из-за двери выскочила Наталья Савишна с скатертью в руке, поймала меня и, несмотря на отчаянное сопротивление о моей стороны, начала тереть меня мокрым по лицу, приговаривая: «Не пачкай скатертей, не пачкай скатертей!»

В этом контексте деепричастие "припрыгивая" выделяется запятыми, потому что оно не выполняет роль наречия (отправился — что делая? — припрыгивая), а обозначает добавочное действие: *шел и прыгал*. Кроме того, деепричастие стоит **перед** глаголом-сказуемым — в этом случае оно обычно обособляется.
Сравните: *Она будила сына улыбаясь. — Улыбаясь, она разбудила сына.*

*Я бежал припрыгивая.* Здесь деепричастие обозначает признак действия и стоит **после** глагола-сказуемого. Деепричастие можно заменить наречием (*Я бежал **вприпрыжку***), и оно не отделяется запятой.

[Необособленное одиночное деепричастие](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5/)

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, разница заключена в том, на какой вопрос отвечает слово припрыгивая:

1) Деепричастие: я отправился что делая? Припрыгивая. Делая это периодически, под настроение, не всё время.

2) Наречие: я отправился как? Припрыгивая. Таков был характер моего движения: прыжками, вприпрыжку, без перерыва.

Чтобы разделить эти два разных смысла, используется запятая.