# Обособление деепричастия "улыбаясь"

Tags: деепричастия

Нужны ли запятые в предложении

"Он закрыл глаза и (?) улыбаясь (?) уснул"?

Comment: Ну запятые с деепричастием вроде всегда нужны или нет? но если, скажем отнести уснул к улыбаясь, то будет забавно: он закрыл глаза, и улыбаясь уснул. И и УСНУЛ можно включить в оборот, поставив запятую перед и, но тогда И это не союз между закрыл и уснул, а просто начало новой фразы, которая в свою очередь смахивает на идиому: улыбаясь уснуть, и улыбаясь уснуть = уснуть с улыбкой.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458988/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc

Comment: Обстоятельство "улыбаясь" можно заменить на "радостно", если вы считаете, что подходит, то пишите без запятых. А здесь не подходит. Например, у Розенталя "говорил улыбаясь", но "думал, улыбаясь" — "говорил радостно" норм, а "думал радостно" нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: *Он закрыл глазА / и **улыбаясь** уснУл.*

Деепричастие в значении **наречия** (с улыбкой).

Сравнить: *Он закрыл глаза и уснУл, // **улыбАясь**.*

Деепричастие обозначает **добавочное действие** (уснул и при этом улыбался).

Выбор знаков зависит от **структуры** предложения и **расстановки** ударений.

Comment: Поняла, спасибо!

Comment: Вы уверены? Здесь "при этом улыбаясь", а не "как уснул". Ударения надо рассматривать, когда по семантике есть варианты. От глагола зависит, а вы формально подходите и считаете, что глагол роли не играет.

Comment: Опять критика? До свидания, не разрешено правилами.  (За друзей голосуем, а других критикуем.)  Вам бы своих ответов больше давать, а не критикой заниматься. Уж покажите себя в деле-то.  И еще послушайте свою речь со стороны, о логике своих сообщений подумайте.

Comment: **По правилам критика разрешена!!!** Ни за кого не голосовал. Да какая критика! Просто информация для размышлений. По-товарищески. Если что-то не так с логикой, то скажите что. Тактика "у вас что-то не так, но не знаю что" идиотская. Ваша неспособность защищать свои ответы говорит о их неверности. Задумайтесь об этом.

Comment: Некуда потратить свой день? Проведите его с друзьями.  И за кого вы голосуете, мне тоже понятно. До свидания!

Comment: Давайте жить мирно. Мои комментарии для улучшения ваших ответов, а не чтобы вас обидеть. Пишите чётко и по делу, чтобы не пришлось тратить много времени, как в предыдущий раз.

Comment: До свидания!...  А мирно живите со своими домочадцами.

Comment: Ваша неспособность защищать свои ответы говорит о их неверности. А ваше нежелание их исправлять говорит о полном наплевательстве на людей, которые спрашивают, и на ответственность, которая на них возложена (например, написать грамотно в книге).

Comment: Хватит уж меня воспитывать, ага?  Вы мне не воспитатель-гувернер.

Comment: Нет вам оправдания!

Answer (score 3):

Если что-то и имеет смысл в том, что такое дополнительное действие, обозначаемое деепричастием, а что характеристика действия, то это следующее:

1. Когда одно действие обозначает способ выполнения другого, как в предложении: ‟Он шёл хромая”, то это характеристика действия (хромание характеризует ходьбу). В такой ситуации обособление не требуется.
2. Когда обозначенное подлежащим выполняет два независимых действия одновременно, как в предложении: ‟Он шёл, напевая”, то это дополнительное действие, и здесь обособление требуется.

Если что-то имеет смысл, то только это. Так что в предложении: ‟Он закрыл глаза и, улыбаясь, уснул” – дополнительное действие и обособления. Это подтверждают примеры из Нац. корпуса:

> Он поехал к отцу и, улыбаясь, сказал... (Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир.)
> Несвицкий, отдуваясь, поднялся и, улыбаясь, подошел к генералу. (Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир.)
> Hélène нагнулась вперед, чтобы дать место и, улыбаясь, оглянулась. (Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир.)

Что касается наречного значения из-за того, что можно заменить ‟улыбаясь” на ‟с улыбкой”. Такая замена не превращает деепричастие в деепричастие с значением наречия: если взять примеры из Нац. корпуса с обособлением, то каждый второй можно так заменить.

> ...потом поднял и, поцаловав, сказал ей изменившимся голосом... ( А. С. Пушкин. Капитанская дочка. ‟Поцаловав” можно заменить на ‟с поцелуем”.)
>
> Молодые люди говорили обо всем русском с презрением или равнодушием и, шутя, предсказывали России участь Рейнской конфедерации.  (А. С. Пушкин. Рославлев. ‟Шутя” можно заменить на ‟с шутками”)
>
> И, ласкаясь, говорила: „Сохрани мой талисман: В нем таинственная сила! (А. С. Пушкин. Талисман. ‟Ласкаясь” можно заменить на ‟с лаской”.)
>
> и тоска овладела мной; и, тоскуя, просиживал я на утесе целые... (М. Ю. Лермонтов. Бэла. ‟Тоскуя” можно заменить на ‟с тоской”.)

Нет правила о том, что при такой замене появляется значение наречия. Это просто кое-кто, как обычно, сочиняет правила на ходу, что вообще-то вводит в заблуждение других пользователей.

Что касается интонации. Во-первых, зачем нам все эти чёрточки и ударения: мы же носители языка, мы знаем, как это произносится. Во-вторых, объяснить отсутствие запятых какой-то другой интонацией не получится, потому что это одиночное деепричастие перед глаголом везде произносится одинаково. Во всех этих предложениях такая же интонация, как и в предложении в вопросе:

> Он поехал к отцу и, улыбаясь, сказал... (Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир.)
> Несвицкий, отдуваясь, поднялся и, улыбаясь, подошел к генералу. (Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир.)
> Hélène нагнулась вперед, чтобы дать место и, улыбаясь, оглянулась. (Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир.)
> Он закрыл глаза и, улыбаясь, уснул.

**Ответ**: обособление требуется.

Comment: Ответы Грамоты.ру об обстоятельственном значении "улыбаясь". Вот ведь они какие: сочиняют, как обычно, правила на ходу, что вообще-то вводит в заблуждение других пользователей.  Или не сочиняют? 
 http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=улыбаясь

Comment: Здесь дополнительное действие имитирует наречие "радостно". Поэтому запятые чаще не ставятся. В языке не всё так гладко и просто, как вам хочется.

Comment: Да, замена так себе, Розенталь немного промахнулся. Он просто хотел передать смысл, никакого практического применения не задумывалось.

Comment: @Jim Korbett спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Нужны.

> Он закрыл глаза и, улыбаясь, уснул.

Деепричастие находится не в конце предложения, а в середине, перед вторым сказуемым.

---

В такой позиции деепричастие должно обособляться.

> Обособление или необособление одиночного деепричастия может зависеть
> от места, занимаемого им по отношению к глаголу-сказуемому: одно и то
> же слово в начале или в середине предложения может обособляться, а в
> конце — нет.
> Ср.: ***Она будила сына улыбаясь. — Улыбаясь, она разбудила сына***;

Похожий пример, позволяющий убедиться в правильности постановки запятых, имеется в **НКРЯ**:

> Не замечая Сапожкова, в кусты забрался счастливый человек, он принес с
> собой солому, лег на нее и, **улыбаясь**, заснул. [Юрий Петкевич. Явление
> ангела (2001)]

Comment: @Sharon Шерон, то, что ваш вариант не совпадает с моим, ничего не значит. Я руководствуюсь общепринятыми рекомендациями и практикой письма (примеры из НКРЯ как раз говорят о том, что запятые необходимы): деепричастие, стоящее между сказуемыми в середине предложения после союза, обособляется. В данном случае на первом месте глагольное значение, а не наречное. Ваше решение очень неудачное, если не сказать неправильное.

Comment: Цитата:  "В данном случае на первом месте глагольное значение, а не наречное". Он закрыл глазА / и улыбаясь уснУл.  На первом месте глагольное значение? Вот глагол у МЕНЯ и выделен ударением (уснУл) , а наречие в безударной позиции. А при обособлении наречия оно у ВАС  получит дополнительное ударение и будет подчеркнуто. Так что всё с точностью наоборот. Приведите в ответе интонационную схему и проверьте.

Comment: @Sharon Глагольное значение у слова "улыбаясь", а не уснул. Наречного значения в этом предложении нет. Дополнительное ударение возникает на деепричастии, поскольку оно стоит после союза "и". Ваш вариант "с улыбкой уснул" я вообще не рассматриваю, потому что он соответствует структуре данного предложения. Еще раз рекомендую посмотреть примеры из НКРЯ: подавляющее большинство примеров доказывает, что в такой позиции деепричастие "улыбаясь" должно выделяться запятыми: на его месте делается пауза. Вы вводите людей в заблуждение, давая некорректные ответы.

Comment: И тут речь не о списывании, а о том, что недопустимо стирать в пыль языковые закономерности.

Comment: А где ваша интонационная схема? Я что-то ее не вижу.  Все одни слова... Кстати, я не возражаю, если вы будете давать свои исключительно корректные ответы. А закономерности каждый понимает по-своему. Я вам не рекомендую употреблять в ответе "должно и обязано", Розенталь говорит о возможности, а не обязательности, он всегда осторожно подбирает слова. До свидания, хорошего вам дня.