# Какую семантику можно выразить в предложении с одиночным деепричастием «улыбаясь»?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастия

Вопрос изменен.

Вот предложение:  ***Он закрыл глаза и (?) улыбаясь (?) уснул.***

Сколько предложений разной структуры можно получить из этого предложения, если переставлять местам **деепричастие и глагол** и выбирать **обособление/необособление** деепричастия? Как при этом меняется значение сообщения?

Комментировать пока не буду, но принять ответ могу сразу.

Мне интересно, как автор выражает нужный ему **смысл**, выбирая **структуру** предложения.

Comment: думая о чем-то приятном/неприятном?

Comment: Нет, я не об этом. Лексическое наполнение не надо менять, это будет то же предложение. Только деепричастие можно переставить и надо выбрать его обособление/необособление.

Answer (score 1):

Четыре разные модели:

1. ***Он закрыл глаза  / и  улыбаясь уснУл.***

Интонация простого  предложение без обособления,  последовательность двух действий.

Деепричастие в значении  обычного обстоятельства (с улыбкой)  в **середине** предложения.

В конце предложения глагол в **ударной** позиции.

2. ***Он закрыл глаза и,  // улыбаясь, //  уснУл.***

Обособление деепричастия внутри предложения, интонационная **вставка**.

Выделение действия, обозначенного деепричастием, в качестве сопутствующей информации.

3. ***Он закрыл глаза  / и уснул улыбАясь***.

Интонация простого  предложение без обособления, последовательность двух действий.

В конце предложения деепричастие в значении  обычного обстоятельства (с улыбкой) в **ударной** позиции.

4. ***Он закрыл глаза и уснУл, // улыбАясь.***

Простое предложение, осложненное  обособленным обстоятельством (деепричастием).

Две интонационные фразы  с полноценным фразовым **ударением** на глаголе и деепричастии.

**ВЫВОД**  (как решаются задачи по пунктуации)

Как мы видим, возможны **четыре разные модели** с точки зрения смысла, грамматики и интонации, оформленные различным образом. **Обособление** одиночного деепричастия – это всегда дополнительное выделение действия, которое должно **соответствовать** замыслу автора.

**Автор** выбирает нужную ему модель (обычно по смыслу и интонации) и ставит знаки.

**Редактор** проверяет все: смысл, интонацию, грамматику, выбор знаков. При этом **учитываются**:  структура предложения,  контекст, просматриваются аналогичные примеры,  подбирается подходящее правило.

**Правила** рекомендуют, как **можно** оформить предложение, но не обязывают (фактически это тоже решенные задачи). Там нет слов «так всегда **должно** оформляться».

**Розенталь:**  «Как известно, русская пунктуационная система обладает большой **гибкостью**: наряду с обязательными правилами она содержит **указания**, не имеющие строго нормативного характера и допускающие пунктуационные **варианты**, необходимые для выражения **смысловых** оттенков и **стилистических** особенностей письменной речи».

**ТЕМА ОБСУЖДАЛАСЬ** [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474619/Обособление-деепричастия-улыбаясь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474619/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8C)

**Он закрыл глаза и улыбаясь уснУл.** Например, долго думал о чем-то и наконец уснул.

**Он закрыл глаза и, улыбАясь, уснУл.** Сравнить: *Он закрыл глаза и, с улыбкой, уснУл.* Деепричастие выделено как вставка.

Выбор делается **по авторскому тексту**. Не стоит редактору говорить: должно быть ***так и только так***, потому что это больше подходит по грамматике и правилам, потому что таких примеров больше. В этом случае он забывает о **структуре и семантике** как конкретного предложения, так и всего текста в целом.

**ОТВЕТЫ ГРАМОТЫ.РУ**

[http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=улыбаясь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8C)

**P.S. ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ НИКОМУ НЕ ДАЕТ ПОКОЯ.**

Говорят **об ударениях**, а интонационной схемы составить не могут.

Говорят **о примерах из Нацкорпуса,** а не видят, что у нас очень простая структура предложения **из 5 слов**. Ну куда здесь **вставочная интонация**?

О **контексте** вообще никто не говорит, а его тоже надо учитывать.

Вот и все доводы: интонацию анализировать не будем, а будем писать **по чужим примерам.** И еще по правилам-рекомендациям, где "возможно и обычно" заменим **на "должно".**

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147444/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.